Conditions where projective hypersurface is nonsingular
Problem: Let $F(X_0,\cdots,X_n)$ be homogenous irreducible polynomial. Let $X=V_P(F)\subset \mathbb P^n$. Prove that $X$ is nonsingular if and only if $\sqrt{(F_{X_0},\cdots,F_{X_n})}=(X_0,\cdots,X_n)$.
To solve the problem, I have solved the following problem in the affine case.
Related Problem (Affine case): If $X\subset \mathbb A^n$ is irreducible affine hypersurface. Then the set of nonsingular points of $X^{sm}$ is an nonempty open set.

Proof. Let $X=V(f)\subset \mathbb A^n$, which is an affine hyperspace, where $f\in k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ is irreducible polynomial. First we will prove the set of singular points is an algebraic closed set. Indeed, the sigular points is the points where $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_2},\cdots,\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}$ vanishes; hence the sigular point set is closed. Hence the singular point set $\operatorname{Sing}X=V\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},\cdots,\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_n},f\right)$. If $\operatorname{Sing}X=X$, then $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},\cdots,\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\in I(X)=(f)$. Since $\deg \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\leq \deg f-1$ for any $i=1,2,\cdots,n$; then $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}=0$. If $\operatorname{char}k=0$, then there is a contradiction. If $\operatorname{char}k=p$, then $f$ is actually a polynomial of $x_i^p$'s. Hence $f=g^p$, where the coefficients of $g$ is the $p$-th root of the coefficients of $f$, which is a contradiction, since $f$ is irreducible as the condition supposed.


I can prove one part of the problem. Here is my proof.

If $\sqrt{(F_{X_0},\cdots,F_{X_n})}=(X_0,\cdots,X_n)$, then $V(F_{X_0},\cdots,F_{X_n})=V(X_0,\cdots,X_n)=\varnothing$. By the argument in the previous problem, $\operatorname{Sing}X=\varnothing$; hence $X$ is nonsingular.

But, I do not have any idea of the other part of the problem. Could you give me some advice?

Update: Suppose $\deg F>1$.

If F is degree 1, the statement isn’t true. So you need to assume deg F > 1 and you can apply the projective nullstellensatz.

@CraniumClamp Sorry, I miss the condition. Let us assume deg F>1, but I still don't know how to apply the projective nullstellensatz. Is the projective nullstellensatz holds for Vp(I) = empty set?
